# WebApi Routing for Custom Method in Controller

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api

I've recently picked up the ASP.NET Web API stuff and whilst I've cracked authorisation and authentication, I can't crack routing. It's a nightmare!

I have created a `Authenticate()` method with an `AuthenticationController`. I add the `[HttpGet]` attribute to `Authenticate()` and yet whenever I hit the API I get a `404`.

Here is my current `WebApiConfig`:-

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "{controller}/{action}");
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
}
```

And the address I am trying is: `/authentication`.

The Controller looks like this:-

```
[BasicHttpAuthorize(RequireAuthentication = true)]
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
     [HttpGet]
      public string Authenticate(string email, string password, string agent, string ip)
      {

      }
}
```

Can anyone direct me in the right direction please? I've tried hitting multiple addresses/endpoints:-

- `/authentication/authenticate`
- `/authentication/`
- `/authentication`

Comment: why do you have 4 routes? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly exactly but you could most likely achieve it with the top (default) route only. if you remove or comment out the last 3 routes and youre using web api then your Authenticate method should be hit when you perform a GET

Comment: Whanks @wal. I removed the 4 top routes - I could see I didn't those and added `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AuthenticateApi",
                routeTemplate: "authenticate",
                defaults: new { controller = "Authentication" }
            );`, everything now seems to work! :)

Comment: @wal, happily award you the answer if you 'officially answer'... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment:

why do you have 4 routes? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly exactly but you could most likely achieve it with the top (default) route only. if you remove or comment out the last 3 routes and youre using web api then your Authenticate method should be hit when you perform a GET